# WMSgetFeatureInfo ProxyHost

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, wms

Does WMSGetFeatureInfo need a proxyhost to allow remote server accessing the data? I use ProxyHost to allow WFS requests, but seems its not working with WMSGetFeatureInfo. the local machines retrieves data from GeoServer successfully but external machines doesn't!

Here is the select feature code:

```
    control = new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo({
        layers: [layer],
        autoActivate: true,
        maxFeatures: 3,
        hover: false,
        infoFormat: "application/vnd.ogc.gml",
        eventListeners: {
            "getfeatureinfo": function (e) {

                var activeLayer = getActiveLayer();
                if (activeLayer != "") {
                    var param = {
                        REQUEST: "GetFeatureInfo",
                        EXCEPTIONS: " application/vnd.ogc.se_xml",
                        BBOX: map.getExtent().toBBOX(),
                        SERVICE: "WMS",
                        VERSION: "1.1.1",
                        X: e.xy.x,
                        Y: e.xy.y,
                        INFO_FORMAT: 'application/vnd.ogc.gml/3.1.1',
                        QUERY_LAYERS: activeLayer.params.LAYERS,
                        Layers: activeLayer.params.LAYERS,
                        FEATURE_COUNT: 6,
                        SRS: 'EPSG:3857',
                        STYLES: activeLayer.params.STYLES,
                        WIDTH: map.size.w,
                        HEIGHT: map.size.h
                    };

                    param.cql_filter = activeLayer.params.CQL_FILTER;

               //     if (activeLayer.params.LAYERS == 'AIS:favoriteVessels');
                //    param.Viewparams = 'UID:' + userid;


                    OpenLayers.loadURL(GeoServerWMS, param, this, setHTML, setHTML);
                    OpenLayers.Event.stop(e);
                }
            }
        }
    });

map.addControl(control);
control.activate();
```

and the GeoServerWMS is specified by:

```
<php
if ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'MYPUBLICIP')
  GeoServerWMS = 'http://MYPUBLICIP:8080/geoserver/wms'
else
  GeoServerWMS = 'http://privateIP:8080/geoserver/wms'
```

here is my allowedHosts

```
allowedHosts = ['localhost', 'localhost:8080','localhost:80', 'localhost:8080/geoserver',
                'PrivateIP','PrivateIP:8080', 'PrivateIP:8080/geoserver',
                'PublicIP','PublicIP:8080', 'PublicIP:8080/geoserver', 
                'www.openlayers.org', 'openlayers.org', 
              ]
```

**EDIT**
Even this event register is not working:

```
selectControl = new OpenLayers.Control.GetFeature({
    id: 'selectControl',
    protocol: OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS.fromWMSLayer(test, {
    url: GeoServerWMS,
        featureType: "layer"
    }),
    hover: false,
    click: true
});
```

Here is the error I get: Some unexpected error occurred. Error text was

> urlopen error [Errno 110] Connection timed out

Comment: Do you see any errors in Firebug? How are you accessing the wms service? Please post the code that you are using.

Comment: updated my post

Comment: Does your proxy file have MYPUBLICIP:8080 in the allowed hosts?

Comment: I added them. updated my post

Comment: what happens if you paste the url into the browser?

Comment: keep loading with showing nothing, then network timeout

Comment: and if I paste the url of private ip, i get the proxy file downloaded

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I'm not sure why you are using the WMSGetFeatureInfo in this particular way. The  getfeatureinfo event is fired, once the control gets the data from the getfeatureinfo request on the WMS service. You just need to show the data on this event.

Please have a look at this sample, which shows a simple WMSGetFeatureInfo control being used: [Feature Info in Popup](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/getfeatureinfo-popup.html)

You don't need to call `OpenLayers.loadURL(GeoServerWMS, param, this, setHTML, setHTML);` Further more, this function is [deprecated](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/doc/apidocs/files/deprecated-js.html#OpenLayers.Ajax.OpenLayers.loadURL), and I'm not even sure if uses the proxy.

If on using a WMSGetFeatureInfo control, like in the given sample, does not work, I would debug the issue, with the following steps:

- Debug the requests using both [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com) & [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org).
- Make sure that the server can route to itself via the external IP. In most enterprise networks, the network routing on the server is severely limited for security reasons, and often it cannot route a request to any external IP, including its own external IP address.

Here is how you would check if the proxy can route to external IP addresses:
Suppose you are using the OpenLayers Proxy like this: `OpenLayers.ProxyHost = "/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi?url=";`

Then, that means that your proxy is at `http://PublicIP/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi`

1. First try to open the Proxy link directly in your browser. If it is the OpenLayers Proxy.cgi file, then it will try to route you to the OpenLayers Site. See if the OpenLayers Site open up.
2. You could also try to open up a page in your allowed hosts. You could try to open `http://PublicIP/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi?url=http://PublicIP:8080/geoserver/web` This should open up the Geoserver Admin Home page.
3. You could also log on to the server and try to open a browser and browse to your external IP, or a well known public website, like google.com. Note that this is not a good idea security-wise, and your system Admin might not be happy with it.

Comment: Thank you. but I tried several versions of getfeature methods such as event register (updated my post)

Comment: Have you checked if the proxy can route to its own external IP address?

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: 1. Yes, this url [http://PublicIP/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi] opened the OpenLayers site. 2. I got this error: This proxy does not allow you to access that location (PublicIP:8080).

Comment: I'm in the same situation http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/111982/proxy-cgi-for-openlayers-reading-from-georss-but-not-from-wfs